# Can I use the Dirichlet's test to prove the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{e^{in}}{n}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

I am trying to state that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{in}}{n}$$ converges.

Is it correct that $|\sum_{n=1}^N e^{in}|\leq M$ for every positive integer $N$?

I.e use $e^{in}$ as the $b_n$ term in Dirichlet's test.

Comment: If you say "there is an $M\in\mathbb{R}$ such that ...", then yes, it's correct. But you need to prove it of course before you use it. It's a geometric sum.

Comment: My confusion comes out because that the partial sum is $1+1+\ldots \leq M$ but I can always take an $N$ such that $N>M$.

Comment: No, $e^{in} \neq 1$ for all $n\in \mathbb{Z}\setminus \{0\}$. That is what makes the partial sums bounded.

Comment: but $n$ is a natural number.

Comment: I think you are right, the bounded series can be taken as a power series, you can evaluate that easily, it is bounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\biggl\lvert\sum_{n=1}^N\mathrm e^{\mathrm in}\biggr\rvert=\biggl\lvert\frac{ e^{\mathrm i}(1-\mathrm e^{\mathrm iN})}{1-\mathrm e^{\mathrm i}}\biggr\rvert\le \frac 2{\lvert1-\mathrm e^{\mathrm i}\rvert}\le\frac{1}{\sin\frac12}.$$

*Justification:*
$\lvert1-\mathrm e^{\mathrm i}\rvert=\sqrt{(1-\cos 1)^2+\sin^2 1}=\sqrt{2(1-\cos 1)}=2\sin\dfrac12$, whence
$$\biggl\lvert\sum_{n=1}^N\mathrm e^{\mathrm in}\biggr\rvert\le\frac{1}{\sin\frac12}$$

Comment: Not sure how you got less than $\sqrt{2}$, but it is certainly bounded. Can we really prove that $|1-e^{i}|>\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: It looks to me like $|1-e^{i}|\approx 0.959$, so your statement is not true. But it is clearly bounded by $3$.

Comment: You're right. It's getting late here, and I computed as if it were $\lvert1-\mathrm i\rvert$.

Comment: @Bernard Something doesn't seem correct.  The middle term is $|\frac{\sin(N/2)}{\sin(1/2)}|$ which for $N=3$ for example, is greater than $2$.

Comment: @Dr MV: I think there's an error in your summation: the exponent in the numerator should be $\mathrm iN$,  not $N+1$. However, I'm beginning to  feel tired, so I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: @Bernard I believe it is correct.  Recall the sum of a geometric progression.

Comment: @Dr MV Yes but you factored out the first term since it does not begin with $1$. Or am I fried?

Comment: The terms $e^{i}$, $e^{i/2}$, and $e^{iN/2}$ have unit magnitude, which facilitates the analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$\left|\sum_{n=1}^N e^{in}\right|=\left|\frac{e^{i}-e^{i(N+1)}}{1-e^{i}}\right|=\left|\frac{\sin(N/2)}{\sin(1/2)}\right|\le \csc(1/2)\approx. 2.085829642933<3$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{in}}{n}=-\ln\left(1-e^i\right)$$

Comment: The radius of convergence of $$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{x^n}{n}$$ is $\rho=1$, so I think you should *at least* provide an argument/result of convergence (since he's asking it and $|e^i|=1$).